# Escape New line character in Spark CSV read

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm working on Spark 2.2.1 version and using the below python code, I can able to escape special characters like @ :
I want to escape the special characters like newline(\n) and carriage return(\r). I replaced the @ which \n, however it didn't worked. Any suggestions please.

**Working:**

```
spark_df = spark.read.csv(file.csv,mode="DROPMALFORMED",inferSchema=True,header =True,escape="@")
```

**Not Working:**

```
spark_df = spark.read.csv(file.csv,mode="DROPMALFORMED",inferSchema=True,header =True,escape="\n")
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your goal is to read csv having textual content with multiple newlines in it, then the way to go is using the spark `multiline option`.

I recently posted some code for [scala there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763661/hive-table-from-csv-the-line-termination-in-quotes/48764063#48764063).

```
val df = spark.read
.option("wholeFile", true)
.option("multiline",true)
.option("header", true)
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
.csv("test.csv")
```

The python syntax will be slightly different but shoud work well.

Comment: Could you please point me out to the right link where I can see Scala code

Comment: I added it in the answer

Comment: Thanks. Requirement is to remove the new lines and is achieved using above answer. I can't upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Thanks. However the above answer use panda, not spark. This won't scale for huge csv.

Comment: I have spark2.2 , but still option multiLine doesn't work.

Comment: Even with multiLine as True, there is still an issue with the  \r\n combination where the \r can be retained.  Using a read statement as above, I have seen it where the rightmost column header ended in \r and some of the rows in that last column also ended with \r.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly as @demongolem suggests.   I get a /r on one of my columns when I use databricks autoloader.  I can't seem to find the way to fix this.

Comment: @leeprevost spark3 has a *linesep* parameter for csv dataframe reader.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this using pandas.

**Sample Code:**

```
pandas_df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
pandas_df = pandas_df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)
pandas_df = pandas_df.replace({r'\\n': ''}, regex=True)
```

You can replace any special character with the above code snippet.

Later on you can convert the pandas_df to spark_df as needed.

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

Comment: This only works if you can actually read the entire file on your local machine with pandas.