# Escape or remove a new line from a file being parsed WITHOUT quotes

Tags: scala, dataframe, csv, apache-spark

I have a csv where a column sometimes contains a new line character (\n or \r), I need to parse this file into a dataframe ignoring or removing those characters BUT these values are NOT surrounded by quotes other wise I could simply add `.option("multiline",true)`

similar question with values surrounded by quotes:
[Escape New line character in Spark CSV read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800046/escape-new-line-character-in-spark-csv-read)

Sample Code:

```scala
val df = spark.read
.option("wholeFile", true)
.option("multiline",true)
.option("header", true)
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
.csv("test.csv")
```

sample input:

```
id,commment,name
1,good,bob
2,bad
,tim
3,fine,sarah
```

sample output:

| id | comment | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | good | bob |
| 2 | bad | null |
| tim | null | null |
| 3 | fine | sarah |

desired output:

| id | comment | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | good | bob |
| 2 | bad | tim |
| 3 | fine | sarah |

*edit* table formatting