# how to load into hive when csv file has cr and lf

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I'm having problem loading my data into a Hive table.The CSV file looks like this

```
"1","2019-11-00","0","0","0","F","","2019-08-12","2019-11-01","2019-10-30","2019-08-12 18:19:52.0","1","0","0","0","0","","0","0","0","000520000400000","3","2019-11-01 11:28:41.0","\
\
cancelled","Ma"
```

this is supposed to be just 1 row. However Hive creates 2 additional rows for:

```
\
cancelled","Ma"
```

Checked Notepad++ and there is a CR at the end of the 1st row and LF at the end of the next 2 rows.

Comment: How are you loading your data into the hive table ?, and please share the script you created with your table in hive

Comment: check dos2unix utility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive table from CSV. The line termination in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763661/hive-table-from-csv-the-line-termination-in-quotes)

Comment: these codes worked for me

sed -e "s/^M//" - removes the carriage returns


gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' removes new lines within double quotes..